# NLog: Dev vs Prod Connection String

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

Does NLog provide a way to set a Connection String based on my current environment.

In Dev I would like to go to my local DB.

In Prod I'd like to go to my Production DB.

I do NOT want to have to manually change a config file before I push an update. Every time I update... I'd rather not maintain multiple config files that I need to remember to update all of them for every change.

Ideally I'd be able to call a utility method that's already controlling which database that gets accessed for the rest of the app.

Comment: You should probably look into publishing, release management and config transforms. If that's too broad, then simply Publish and config transforms. If you're not using ASP.Net, then you may need to look into SlowCheetah.

Comment: are you using .net core at all?

Comment: Not using .NET Core.

Comment: I'm currently publishing via the Azure SDK. It has it's own xxx.Cloud.cscfg and xxx.Prod.cscfg. That still has me maintaining multiple config files which I would rather not do.

Comment: This actually doesn't have much to do with NLog itself. As @YuriyFaktorovich suggested, you should look into release management. Whether you're going for publishing or transform is a matter of preference up to a point, but I'd say you have to address that "at large", and not only regarding your logging.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the connection string into a global-variable at startup:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Gdc-layout-renderer

Then you can reference this global-variable from the database-target, using the ConnectionString-property.

```
<target name="database" xsi:type="Database" connectionString="${gdc:item=MyCustomProperty}">
   <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />
</target>
```

Comment: That will work for more than just the Layout attribute? If so, that sounds like exactly what I want. Will give it a go and see.

Comment: It can only be used on Layout-properties. `Database.ConnectionString` is a Layout-property.

Comment: The way I understood it was that the <target> section was where the database information needed to be and the <layout> section was for formatting. Do you have an example of the <layout> section having the database information?

Comment: Layout is a datatype (like string). Some NLog targets has a property called Layout of the type Layout. But the Database-Target does not. The Database-target mainly uses its Parameters (each with their individual Layout). I was guessing you already had an example running, and knew how to write xml-attributes. Have now added some example xml.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Slow Cheetah](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms), we use it for all our config files (App.Config. Web.Config, NLog.Config, etc).

It can transform lines or complete parts of the config XML depending on our compiling build configuration, Debug/Staging/Release.